# If I write the description of an image, then I do not see where they appear

Tags: bug

When I introduce an Image in my answer, there is a *description* to be given. But then it does not appear in the published version, not even when hovering over the image (would be cool to have something xkcd style).

Is it a bug or is it a feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a feature; see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144080/552049) on the main meta.

The short version is that the description isn't used for a XKCD-style mouseover text, but as a replacement text in case the image cannot be displayed, e.g. by screen readers or if the image doesn't load. That is, the description matches the intended use case for the `alt` attribute in the HTML spec. Even though the XKCD mouseover text is often called an "alt text", it really uses the `title` HTML attribute.

One way of including a mouseover text on Stack Exchange sites is as follows

`[![Underwater basket weaving - description for screen readers ][1]][1]`

`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngekA.png "Underwater basket weaving - description showing up when hovering over image"`

which results in

[image: Underwater basket weaving - description for screen readers]

Inspecting the picture element in my browser, the corresponding HTML is

`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngekA.png" alt="Underwater basket weaving - description for screen readers " title="Underwater basket weaving - description showing up when hovering over image">`

Comment: The "description for screen readers" ("alt") also shows up when images don't load for any reason (e.g., network firewall or disabling images to save data).